# Does python WSGI supports IPv6?

Tags: python, wsgi

I am using python WSGI module for servicing IPv4 http requests. Does WGSI support IPv6 requests? Can it listen to IPv6 IP port combination?

Answer (score 1):

WSGI is completely unconcerned with IP versions; it is a specification for communication between a webserver and Python code. It is up to your server - Apache, nginx, gunicorn, uwsgi, whatever - to listen to the port.

Comment: well I think that statement is only 90% true: If you are indeed using the "python WSGI module" (as in `wsgiref.simple_server.WSGIServer` without any additional webserver in front) then this question is actually valid.